# Microsoft Excel has stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I use the arrow key to scroll down, Excel stops working:

[image]

And I get this:

[image]

Comment: you tagged this with `vba` do you have any macro running in that file?

Comment: Yes. ListFillRange, Sorry I'm newbie

Comment: Dropdown Menu (ActiveX Control Combo Box) That Does Not Scroll using mouse

Comment: I suppose there's no such problem in a plain spreadsheet (without `vba` macro) ; the problem might then be coming from your `vba` script. If so, if you can, you should post the macro you use as part of your question ; or debug it with the macro editor.

Comment: Dropdown Menu (Combo Box) That Does Not Scrolling using arrow key and shows the message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quickly rule out problems with excel itself, type in run dialog (Winkey + R) - `excel /a`. This starts excel for COM and means no customisation of excel. Does your error occur now.

Get the error details. In settings search for *View Problem Details*. Right click your error and choose *View Technical Details*. Post those here.

It will look something like this.

```
Description
A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: AppHangXProcB1
Application Name:   iexplore.exe
Application Version:    11.0.10240.16412
Application Timestamp:  55b99d3f
Hang Signature: d229
Hang Type:  134742048
Waiting on Application Name:    iexplore.exe
Waiting on Application Version: 11.0.10240.16412
OS Version: 10.0.10240.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  3081
Additional Hang Signature 1:    d2293b30a82e02c1d065885655e2fc11
Additional Hang Signature 2:    e68d
Additional Hang Signature 3:    e68d7530cc359e253127575d50ba30e2
Additional Hang Signature 4:    d229
Additional Hang Signature 5:    d2293b30a82e02c1d065885655e2fc11
Additional Hang Signature 6:    e68d
Additional Hang Signature 7:    e68d7530cc359e253127575d50ba30e2
```

**Decoding Errors**

-2147220978 style numbers are 32 bit signed integers, convert to hex =
with calculator.

Windows errors (smallish numbers) and  COM HResults (typically, but with =
exceptions, start with an 8 as in 0x80040154) are defined in WinError.h, =
except 8007nnnn where you look up the Window error number that it =
contains.

As a general rule Windows errors are less than 65,535 (0xFFFF). Errors =
starting 0x80000001 are Component Object Model (COM) HResults. Errors =
starting 0xC0000001 are NTStatus results. Errors starting 0xD0000001 are =
also NTStatus values returned in a HResult.

NTStatus errors (typically but not always start with an C as in =
0xC0000022) are defined in NTStatus.h.=20

.h files are the best source because it includes the symbolic name of =
the error which can give clues such as the source of the error. =
FormatMessage doesn't give the symbolic name only the description.

You get these files by downloading the Platform SDK (it's gigabytes)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx%3Fid%3D8279&sa=3DU&e=
i=3Dw2IrULDDLsHFmAWbmIHoBg&ved=3D0CBwQFjAA&usg=3DAFQjCNHZn9-4f2NnuN9o3UWU=
sOF3wL7HBQ

If you just want the two files I have them on my skydrive so I can =
reference them anywhere I go.
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3DE2F0CE17A268A4FA!121

Note internet errors (12,000 - 12,999) are windows errors but are =
specified in wininet.h also available above.=20

There are errors defined in other .h files. But 99% are in the three =
above.

**Structure of HResults and NTStatus Codes**

The most significant bit in HResults, and the two most significant bits =
in NTStatus are set on error. Hence Hresults start 8 on error and =
NTStatus starts C on Error. The next 14 or 15 bits are reserved and some =
specify the facility - what area the error is in. This is the third and =
fourth number when reading hex. EG 0xnn07nnnn - An HResult facility code =
7 is a normal Windows' error (returned from a COM program - hence it's =
returned as a HResult). Facility codes are defined in Winerror.h for =
HResults and NTStatus.h for NTStatus codes. They are different.

**To Decode 0x8003nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility code 3 means the HResult contains OLE Structured =
Storage errors (0x0 to 0xff). These are the same as Dos error codes. =
These don't seem to be in Windows' header files and the list of codes is =
at the end of this post.

**To Decode 0x8004nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility code 4 means the HResult contains OLE errors (0x0 =
to 0x1ff) while the rest of the range (0x200 onwards) is component =
specific errors so 20e from one component will have a different meaning =
to 20e from another component.

This is why the source of the error is extra important for errors above =
0x80040200.

**To Decode 0x8007nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility code 7 means the HResult contains a Windows' =
error code. You have to look up the Windows' error code not the HResult.

To decode 0x80070002. The 0x means it's a hexadecimal number, the 8 =
means error, the first 7 means it a windows error, and the rest of the =
number, 2, is the actual Windows error.

To look up the error we need it in decimal format. Start Calculator =
(Start - All Programs - Accessories - Calculator) and choose View menu - =
Scientific, then View menu - Hex. Enter 2. Then View menu -  Decimal. It =
will say 2.

Start a Command Prompt (Start - All Programs - Accessories - Command =
Prompt) and type

net helpmsg 2

and it will say

The system cannot find the file specified.

or look it up in winerror.h

```
  //
  // MessageId: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  //
  // MessageText:
  //
  // The system cannot find the file specified.
  //
  #define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND             2L
```

**To Decode 0x8019nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility 0x19 are HTTP errors. Codes under 16,384 (0x4000) =
are the same as HTTP errors, eg HTTP status 404: The requested URL does =
not exist on the server is 0x80190194 (0x194 =3D 404). Codes 16,384 and =
higher are BITS specific.

**To Decode 0xDnnnnnnn Errors**

HResults starting 0xD are an HResult with a NTStatus value in it. Just =
cange the lead D to a C and treat as an NTStatus (Hresult =3D NTStatus =
OR 10000000).